# Save Work Done In MS Word To A Database Not On A Hard Drive

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I want to save my work done in Microsoft Word 2013 to a database and not on a hard disk.  That is, assuming the document contains formatted text, pictures and styles, I want to save the document as it is in a Microsoft SQL server database and be able to retrieve back to ms word as it was saved in the database.

I desperately need help, PLEASE!!!

Below is the code I used to save the word document to sql database:

```
    public void SaveNewDocument()
    {
        try
        {

            int len = Application.ActiveDocument.Content.StoryLength;
            byte[] docData = new byte[len];

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ms.Read(docData, 0, len);
                this.table_2TableAdapter.Insert("FirstFile", docData);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message, "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

When I go the database the data is there.

Below is the code I used to retrieve from the database and it's not working:

```
    private void ThisDocument_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.GetExistingFile();
    }

    private void GetExistingFile()
    {
        this.table_2TableAdapter.Fill(this.officeAppDataSet.Table_2);

        var query = from f in this.officeAppDataSet.Table_2.AsEnumerable()
                    where f.Id == 4
                    select f;
        foreach (var mFile in query)
        {
            string fileName = mFile.FileName;
            byte[] fileData = mFile.FileData;
            int len = int.MaxValue;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ms.Write(fileData, 0, len);
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is the error message: ArgumentException was unhandled:
Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.

Comment: You can use OleDB or Office Interop-Assembly to read your content. First of all save your work on on your hard drive, then head back to us if you have problems

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using is extremely inefficient and I wouldn't recommend the process, but the reason that you code is failing is your length.... when you are saving your `MemoryStream` you are setting the length `int len = Application.ActiveDocument.Content.StoryLength;` but when you try to retrieve it, you are setting it `int len = int.MaxValue;` which would be far past the end of the data stream.

Comment: Hmmmm! Andrew, this is where am at a loss. My main concern is how to be able to get word to open with the data I stored. I don't want to use content controls, because naturally users will not be typing into them when they are creating documents with images and styles. I am investigating your advice now.